# C# Linq Dictionary IO

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, io, statistics

**How can I do this with LinQ?**

I have a txt file.(Its about 100 lines long.)

```
6 7
0/3 # ##t#kon tu#i#do#b#n ko#yk####a#s##ttak###lk##ul$$$$#$#$$$####$$$$#$$$$$$#$$#$$$$$#$
```

I stored it in a Dictionary (The two lines).

```
alap = File.ReadAllLines("veetel.txt");
Dictionary<string,string> statisztikaDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
for (int z = 1; z < alap.Length; z+=2)
{
     statisztikaDictionary.Add(alap[z],alap[z-1]);
}
```

The first line so in this the 6 is the day of record the 7 is the pesons id who recorded.
I need to create a statistics about it so.
Write it out like this:

```
Day:Number of persons who made a record.
```

I counted so the person number and the day value varies from 0-11 but we "don't" know this.
The second line starts with a 0/3 that means 0 adult 3 child. I need to read 2 values a day and an ID and print out how many wolfs the person observed(In this case 3).
I am training for my final exam and I got stuck with this. Any help would be apriciated,

Comment: Your question is unclear... what is the *exact* problem that you are having?

Comment: I don't know how to do the Day:Number thing with LinQ

Comment: Well how would you do it without Linq? what have you tried/researched?

Comment: This was my best shot: var duplicateValues = sortedDict.GroupBy(x => x.Key).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);

Comment: Why do you use Dictionary? Can you provide few lines of text file more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to create custom class which can hold/store related data. Let it be `Statisztika` with the following fields/properties: `Day`, `PersonId`, `Visitor` and `CountOfVisits`.

`Statisztika` class definition:

```
public class Statisztika
{
    private int iday = 0;
    private int ipersonid = 0;
    private int ivisitor =0;
    private int icount =0;

    //class constructor
    public Statisztika(string[] twolines)
    {
        iday = Convert.ToInt32(twolines[0].Split(' ')[0]);
        ipersonid = Convert.ToInt32(twolines[0].Split(' ')[1]);
        //we have to replace these lines:
        //ivisitor = Convert.ToInt32(twolines[1].Split('/')[0]);
        //icount = Convert.ToInt32(twolines[1].Split('/')[1].Split(' ')[0]);
        //with:
        //check for single slash
        int pos = twolines[1].IndexOf("/");
        if (pos>-1)
        {
            //in case of error TryParse method returns zero
            Int32.TryParse(twolines[1].Substring(0,pos)
                .Replace("#", "").Trim(), out ivisitor);
            Int32.TryParse(twolines[1].Substring(pos+1,2)
                .Replace("#","").Trim(), out icount);
        }
    }

    public int Day
    {
        get {return iday;}
        set {iday = value;}
    }

    public int PersonId
    {
        get {return ipersonid;}
        set {ipersonid = value;}
    }

    public int Visitor
    {
        get {return ivisitor;}
        set {ivisitor = value;}
    }

    public int CountOfVisits
    {
        get {return icount;}
        set {icount = value;}
    }
}
```

As you can see, to create `Statisztika` object, you need to pass two lines of text (from the file) to be able to initiate fields. Now, we need to create `List<Statisztika>`. Imagine, it's data container. To get data from this list, we can use Linq query.

**Usage:**

```
string sFileName = @"D:\veetel.txt";
string[] alap = File.ReadAllLines(sFileName);

List<Statisztika> stat = new List<Statisztika>();
for(int i=0; i<alap.Length; i+=2)
{
    //Linq rules! 
    string[] twolines = alap.Skip(i).Take(2).ToArray();
    //create new Statisztika object and add to list
    stat.Add(new Statisztika(twolines));
}

//use create linq query, group data by day and visitor type ;)
var qry = stat
    .GroupBy(p=>new{p.Day, p.Visitor})
    .Select(grp=>new
            {
                Day = grp.Key.Day,
                Visitor = grp.Key.Visitor,
                SumOfVisits = grp.Sum(p=>p.CountOfVisits)
            })
    .OrderBy(a=>a.Day)
    .ThenBy(a=>a.Visitor);

Console.WriteLine("Day Visitor SumOfVisits");
foreach(var sta in qry)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", sta.Day, sta.Visitor, sta.SumOfVisits);
}
```

Sample output:

```
Day Visitor SumOfVisits
1  0  0
2  0  0
2  1  0
3  0  0
3  2  15
4  0  0
5  0  0
6  0  12
7  0  9
7  1  9
8  0  0
9  0  0
9  1  0
10  0  0
11  0  0
11  1  0
11  3  0
11  13  0
```

**[EDIT]**

Note: If `\` (slash) does not exists, `Statisztika` class constructor uses zero's in `Visitor` and `CountOfVisits` fields/members.

If you would like to check if code works properly, use this code:

```
string sFileName = @"D:\veetel.txt";
    string[] alap = File.ReadAllLines(sFileName);
    for(int i=0; i<alap.Length; i+=2)
    {
        int one = 0;
        int two = 0;
        string[] twolines = alap.Skip(i).Take(2).ToArray();
        int pos = twolines[1].IndexOf("/");
        if(pos>-1)
        {
            Int32.TryParse(twolines[1].Substring(0,pos)
                     .Replace("#", "").Trim(), out one);
            Int32.TryParse(twolines[1].Substring(pos+1,2)
                     .Replace("#","").Trim(), out two);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", 
                      twolines[1].Substring(0,8), one, two);
    }
```

Above code produces output as follow:

```
#abor# #  0  0
ta###t##  0  0
0/# a #a  0  0
a pat#k#  0  0
e#zakrol  0  0
1/3#sot#  1  3
0/# a pa  0  0
#3/0#s#t  3  0
verofe#y  0  0
ta#o#t#v  0  0
eszakro#  0  0
#/3#so##  0  3
...etc.
```

Cheers, Maciej

Comment: Thank you for taking your time with helping me. Although this gives a format excetion:  ivisitor = Convert.ToInt32(twolines[1].Split('/')[0]);

Comment: Interesting... I copied sample data provided by you. I don't get any exceptions... Does second line start with `0/3` ?

Comment: This is the full text file.

Comment: So... it looks like the second line can contain different data, such as: `#/3`, '#/#', `0/#`, etc. Some lines does not contain any information about visitor and count of visits... I'l; try to improve my answer, but now in Poland is about 0:00 AM. Please, be patient...

Comment: Thank you very much. Greetings from Hungary. :)

Comment: You're very welcome ;) Did you know that "Pole and Hungarian cousins be"? Don't you believe? Please, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_Hungarian_cousins_be

Comment: I did know this :) It's a really nice poem.

Comment: Yeah, poem based on historical facts. Cheers, Maciej

Comment: Could you suggest me some books to learn from?(C#) (Maybe your book? :)

Comment: I do not have any book about C# programming and i can't recommend any. Check free wikibooks: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming and use MSDN documentation (type in your default browser this statement: "c# msdn"). That's all ;)

Comment: Thanks, oh I see your book is about VBN.

Comment: Yeah, it was years ago... I started programming with VB and VBA, then i wanted to know different languages, such as: C++, C#, Assembler. At this moment my favorite is C# ;)

Comment: I have another task I need to find a specific string in the messages and print the person id and day. Any idea?

Comment: Please, post another question and notify me via comment. I'll promise to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78011/discussion-between-maciej-los-and-hambalko-bence).

Answer (score 2):

I guess you prefer some guidance instead of a working code as the full solution.

To be able to query a dictionary for the amount of persons that recorded observations in certain day, and to query for the amount of wolves observed by a person in certain day, I would create a dictionary with a key composed by day and personId and value as observation data.

See below for an example of 2 classes to hold keys and values for your dictionary.

For keys:

```
public class ObservationId
{
    public int Day;
    public int PersonId;

    public ObservationId(int day, int personId)
    {
        this.Day = day;
        this.PersonId = personId;
    }
    public ObservationId(string line)
    {
        // Add code here to split data in the line to fill day and personId values
    }
}
```

For values:

```
public class ObservationData
{
    public int Adults;
    public int Childs;
    public int TotalWolves
    {
        get { return this.Adults + this.Childs; }
    }
    public ObservationData(int adults, int childs)
    {
        this.Adults = adults;
        this.Childs = childs;
    }
    public ObservationData(string line)
    {
        // Add code here to split data in the line to fill values for adults and childs (and optionally the rest of data)
    }
}
```

To fill data from the file:

```
        string[] alap;
        alap = File.ReadAllLines("veetel.txt");
        Dictionary<ObservationId, ObservationData> statisztikaDictionary = new Dictionary<ObservationId, ObservationData>();
        for (int z = 1; z < alap.Length; z += 2)
        {
            ObservationId id = new ObservationId(alap[z - 1]);
            ObservationData data = new ObservationData(alap[z]);
            statisztikaDictionary.Add(id, data);
        }
```

To search by day and person ID:

```
    public int GetTotalWolves(int day, int personId)
    {
        ObservationId id = new ObservationId(day, personId);
        if (statisztikaDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            return statisztikaDictionary[id].TotalWolves;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

To search for a day (using Linq):

```
    public int GetObservationsByDay(int day)
    {
        return statisztikaDictionary.Where(o => o.Key.Day == day).Count();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I appriciate that you took time helping for me.

Comment: This somehow gives an error that the statisztikaDictionary is net defined but it is so i have no clue why. It gives the error in the 2 methods.

Comment: These 2 methods could access the dictionary if declared in the same scope. For example, if you declare the dictionary in a form and include these 2 methods in the same form; or if you include the dictionary in a class, and the 2 methods in the same class, like in the excelent answer from Maciej Los